# Posting to Twitter account using Windows .bat file code

Tags: bash, command-line, github, ssh

I'm trying to setup an automatic tweet script that runs after a git commit. I'm using Windows 7 have curl available in the command line.

I'm not sure how to set variables with the language windows scripts run and also am not positive about the oauth process.

I have the api key and secret, and also the consumer key and secret but I'm just not sure how to wrap it all together.

Here is a paper clipped mashup of code I'm trying to use as a foundation:

```
#!/bin/sh

# PATH modification needed for http_post and oauth_sign
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

toplevel_path=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
toplevel_dir=`basename "$toplevel_path"`

branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
subject=`git log --pretty=format:%s -n1`
hashtags="#code #$toplevel_dir"
tweet=$hashtags' ['$branch']: "'$subject'"'

# truncate tweets that are longer than 140 characters
if [ ${#tweet} -gt 140 ]
    then
        tweet_trunc=$(echo $tweet | cut -c1-137)
        tweet=${tweet_trunc}...
fi

//set vars
consumer_key="mPijnvYpD0sHAY8r*******"
consumer_secret="OWuvuyQeYrT3ToJgyvNdR6baNuDldmTDF5IIJCI************"
access_token="2476143012-ld78CrgnNY3kUmD0QRdvIchXeDC13nO3********"
access_secret="3HTdOlf8jCVzPi5I9usV7rIbGFtM5f****************"

//build oauth
//post data

//example curl code found during research
curl --request 'POST' 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="mPijnvYpD0sHAY8r6fkox0KBj", oauth_nonce="OWuvuyQeYrT3ToJgyvNdR6baNuDldmTDF5IIJCIablQbyHA2PS", oauth_signature="Ba6IB8uH2SjtrK8a%2FgZnqCgvIKs%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1346207448", oauth_token="14814762-vvYtBOLX8hBAQ0i0f1k4wxrioG1jOk49MJrqn3myE", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose -F "media[]=@mack.jpg" -F "status=Test from cURL" --header "Expect: "
```

Any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused.  You want to use a windows .bat file, but the posted script is a unix-style shell script.  [GNU bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) != [windows batch files](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true).  (though there are ports of bash to windows).  Not to mention the [tag:c++] style comments `//`

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure what language I was working with. I understand now. Git hooks run unix shell commands. Not ssure how to comment on shell scripts.

Comment: I discovered Zapier.com can handle this process. Am happy.

Answer (score 1):

Bro, on Windows you should use PowerShell now. `.bat` is lame!

```
$toplevel_path = git rev-parse --show-toplevel
$toplevel_dir = Split-Path $toplevel_path -Leaf
$branch = git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
$subject = git log --pretty=format:%s -n1
$hashtags = "#code #$toplevel_dir"
$tweet = '{0} [{1}]: "{2}"' -f $hashtags, $branch, $subject

if ($tweet.length -gt 140) {
  $tweet = $tweet.substring(0,137)
}

$oauths =
  'oauth_consumer_key="mPijnvYpD0sHAY8r6fkox0KBj"',
  'oauth_nonce="OWuvuyQeYrT3ToJgyvNdR6baNuDldmTDF5IIJCIablQbyHA2PS"',
  'oauth_signature="Ba6IB8uH2SjtrK8a%2FgZnqCgvIKs%3D"',
  'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"',
  'oauth_timestamp="1346207448"',
  'oauth_token="14814762-vvYtBOLX8hBAQ0i0f1k4wxrioG1jOk49MJrqn3myE"',
  'oauth_version="1.0"'

$header = 'Authorization: OAuth {0}' -f ($oauths -join ',')

curl --verbose --request POST -F 'media[]=@mack.jpg' `
  -F 'status=Test from cURL' --header 'Expect: ' `
  --header $header https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json
```

- command substitution is actually better than with Bash
- PowerShell "printf" is cool
- arrays are cool
- the continuation character `` ` `` is too small though, hard to see

Comment: Hey Steven, thank you mate. I shot myself in the foot before I entered the bar. It looks like the script I am working with is unix shell code that I'm trying to set to automatically run post-commit via the .git/hooks/post-update file. Will the above still work for my case?

Comment: @atwellpub it should, I dont really work with hooks though, so not sure.